# Modifying Access Database using OleDb with C++

Tags: c++, ms-access, oledb

Most of what is online about OleDb regards C# and I am using C++.
I have it working for displaying the records, but I am not sure how to get it to add records to the database

Comment: Can you use DotNet framework and CLR?

Comment: I have the program working with CLR